# C++ replacing member variables with values from other types

Tags: c++, templates, types

I have a class T with n member variables, for example

```
class T{
  ushort name;
 ushort id;
 double value;
.....etc...
};
```

I also have a collection of classes T1, T2....,  each consisting of member variables
which are subsets of member variables of T (for lack of a better word, let me call
this a subset type of T).  For example, T1 may be

```
class T1 {
 ushort name;
 double value;
};
```

which just picks up two members of T.

I would like to write a method

```
template <typename X> 
T join(T t, X x)
```

where we return a class of type T, by replacing values of each member variable in t, with
those of x (provided X is a sub-type of T) and the other values of t remain the same.

I can think of doing this via specializations. But there should be an elegant method of doing this (perhaps detecting when a type X is a subset-type of T and doing the right thing).

Answer (score 0):

> I can think of doing this via specializations. But there should be an elegant method of doing this (perhaps detecting when a type X is a subset-type of T and doing the right thing).

"Detecting" is part of specialization. You should provide specializations for "subset"-types and provide no implementation for generic specialization (to provoke compilation error, when someone uses other types with that method).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to provide specializations for all subset types. You can try to use the member detector idiom: [Member Detector](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Member_Detector), or **__if_exist** if you are using MSVC. 
So you only need to write [number of members in T] * 2 macros(and if use MSVC, you don't need the SetXXX) instead of specializing all possible combinations of members in T

```
CREATE_MEMBER_DETECTOR(name);
CREATE_MEMBER_DETECTOR(id);
CREATE_MEMBER_DETECTOR(value);
......

template<int N, typename T, typename R>
class SetName
{ 
public:
   void operator()(T& t, R& r)
   {
   }
};

template<typename T, typename R>
class SetName<1, T, R>
{
public:
   void operator()(T& t, R& r)
   {
      t.name = r.name;
   }
};
......
(can be macros too)
```

And the join() should be:

```
template <typename SUBSET> 
T join(T t, SUBSET x)
{
   SetName<Detect_name<SUBSET>::value, T, SUBSET>()(t, x);
   SetValue<Detect_value<SUBSET>::value, T, SUBSET>()(t, x);
   ......

   return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeifo>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct SetBase
{
    T first;
    T second;
    SetBase(const T& first = T(), const T& second = T()) 
    : first(first), second(second)    {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Set : public SetBase<T>
{
   short name_id;
   Set(const T& first = T(), const T& second = T(), const short& name) :
   SetBase<T>(first, second), name_id(name){}
};

template<typename Class, typename BaseClass>
Class* join(Class **a, BaseClass *b)
{
    if(typeid(Class) != typeid(BaseClass))
    {
        Class* retval = new Class(*static_cast<Class*>(b));
        retval->name_id = (*a)->name_id;
        *a = retval;
    }
    else
    {
        Class* retval = new Class(*b);
        *a = retval;
    }
    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    Set<int> *a = new Set<int>(1, 2, 3);
    SetBase<int> *b = new SetBase<int>(4, 5);
    cout << join(&a, b)->first << " " << join(&a, b)->second << " " << join(&a, b)->name_id << "\n";
    cout << a->first << " " << a->second << " " << a->name_id << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The Set class is public derived from SetBase, so the cast that I use is valid

Comment: This won't work when passing to join() 2 agruments of SubSetClass

Answer (score 0):

I would implement conversion from T1...Tn to T (or some class that is derived from T and has info which members are actually set), and then implement join() function in terms of T. Don't think this is good place for template magic actually